# "No BlackBerry JRE is installed" while creating new Blackberry project with Eclipse JDE Plugin 1.3 !

Tags: eclipse, facebook, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, rim-5.0

I downloaded Eclipse Helios "BlackBerry JDE PluginFull 1.3". I installed it, and installation process terminated successfully. But Whenever I try to create a new BB project, i got the following message:

> No BlackBerry JRE is installed. 
> Please click "Configure JREs..." link to configure a BlackBerry JRE

When i click the "configure JREs" link, I find that the configuration contains JRE6, but still the dropdown of creating a new project can't detect the JRE ! I checked installed JREs in Eclipse, I found that JRE6 is installed and is checked to be used as default. 
 So I added a new installed JRE files, from preferences window in Eclipse and I made it point to the JRE6 installed in File System. Finally I tried to create a new project with this new created JRE, still the problem exists !

I searched online for the issue, and I found many users say to update from help menu using 
 http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java 
I used it and I chose Blackberry Java SDK 5.0 , after installation successfully process this didn't solve the issue

Any suggestions or advises ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution: Simply, **RESTART THE MACHINE** !